# How can I find all subversion repositories that need committing?

Tags: svn

I'm pretty new to subversion. I use TortoiseSVN at the moment and like it so would like to stick with it.

However, I do have a problem. We have a number of subversion repositories, each containing either a single product, general code library stuff or a customer's code. I'm curently connected up to about 20 repositories.

As I am called upon to make changes to many of these daily, it's easy to not spot that one of them has been updated and not committed, leading me to have changes locally that haven't been added to the repository for several days.

Is there a solution to this problem? It would be good if there was a way to check for changes for all of the repositories on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of choices.  With TortoiseSVN you can just select the SVN Commit option and it will show anything which requires committing (Explorer should also change the overlay icon from a green tick if something has changed and not been committed).

The other option is to run "svn status" from the command line under the root directory for the solution.  This will show modified and uncontrolled files which you can then either commit directly from the command line or jump back to TortoiseSVN and commit from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

- put all your working copies in one folder (or have a file listing the working copies)
- take `svn status` and loop over all of these WCs.
- if `svn status` indicates that something's dirty, go there and commit.

You could either start the script manually to find the files or cyclic (as scheduled task).

To get notified if any of the repos was updated from someone else, you could use something like the CommitMonitor: http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor.html